# I reopened a file and I lost all textures and materials :(

Tags: materials, texture-painting

I was working on a file and saved it and closed blender when I reopened it was all black, no materials no textures nothing, is it all lost or is there a way I can recover something? If not do I have to start it all agaiN???????[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, can you tell a bit more? Did you change the files location? Please take screenshot with a proper tool, show us the shader editor where the material should be. Do you have any of the blend1 files in your folder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Textures are external image files, if you didn't pack them. If you don't save them as image files to a folder, they will lost. Sometimes even while Blender is running.